# Why is the frequency response of an LED important?

Tags: frequency-response, small-signal, optics, oled, bit-rate

I'm working on visible light communication where I fabricate my own organic LEDs. One of the ways to characterize them is "small signal analysis." I understand we are applying this analysis to see the bandwidth of the OLED, but I do not understand how this bandwidth is related to the communication side.

Some people directly apply a bitstream to the LED while some modulate the bitstream with AC and apply. What is the difference?

Comment: Modulation helps you massage the signal so it fits within the LED's frequency response. (or e.g. the amplifier's frequency response)

Comment: @user253751 i understand that but what I dont understand how AC frequency response represent the DC digital On Off Keying for instance? because the only way led can be modulated is "intensity modulation". In AC I have peak to peak so i'm turning on and off the device twice compared to DC.

Comment: @winny you can use both for displays and communication. displays consists of millions of pixels which are basically individual organic or inorganic leds.

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful there are a whole lot of other waveforms apart from "on and off" and "on and off twice as fast"!

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful but suppose you do just turn it on and off. So you get this on-and-off signal, like a square wave. What are the frequencies in a square wave?

Comment: @winny OP writes _"where I fabricate my own organic LEDs"_, so I don't think there's a datasheet. I'd be very interested in the howto on DIY OLEDs, though!

Answer (score 8):

> how this bandwidth is related to communication side?

Since this deals with optical telecommunication, I think it is relatively easy to see why the frequency response would be important. If you have an LED that can modulate quickly, then you can send bits at a higher rate.

> Also some people directly applies bitstream to LED while some modulating bitstream with AC and apply. What is the difference?

The most straight-forward approach for sending data through light, is using a Non-Return-to-Zero scheme (NRZ) where you just turn on the light for a '1' and turn it off for a '0'. There are encodings that guarantee enough edges to keep finding the signal even when there is background light but you might still modulate it to distinguish it more easily. Nevertheless, there are many more modulation schemes that can (if the noise is low enough) allow you to encode more information than an NRZ scheme. For example, you could encode information by frequency modulation (FM) or amplitude modulation (AM), or you can encode information in both phase shifts and amplitude (QAM), etc. You can even have multiple frequency bands working in parallel.

Answer (score 7):

Bandwidth of something is generally defined to be the frequency range where the AC waveform amplitude drops by 3dB. That's the half power point.

The larger bandwidth you have the faster you can turn the LED on and off (or modulate it) to send data. For example send square wave at 100 kHz, it will still look like 100 kHz square wave as the LED can fully turn on and off at the rate it can. But because the LED has some finite speed to turn on and off, at 100 MHz it may not be able to fully turn on and off any more. So it has limited bandwidth.

Sometimes the LED can be directly driven with data stream, but sometimes it may need to be modulated for some reason, as it would not othwerwise pass through the system.

For example, if you use 1 Mbps data rate and make a receiver for it, the receiver circuitry might work if there is enough transitions in the data, like if it ideally is 50% high and low, but if the detector has automatic gain control to adjust itself to varying ambient light conditions and varying data signal powers due to distance or whatever, too long light pulse or too long time between light pulses may cause the receiver to disregard a too long pulse as ambient light or consider too long space between pulses to adjust it to original ambient light.

Therefore the transmitted data is modulated or encoded for it to pass the system and not be affected much by the data pattern.

Comment: is AC waveform basically the worst case scenario that LED can turn on and off? Because AC has peak to peak so it should be turning on-off the device twice compared to DC binary. i also do not understand why AC is applied? why not DC-DC? Because in AC-DC case, the device is already on within linear range with DC bias and we are superimposing AC on top of that with bias tee. Super confused really.

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful It helps to realise that switched on/off DC (a square wave) is also just AC, but containing many harmonics that add up to the square shape. In fact, a perfectly sharp transition between two DC levels requires infinitely many harmonics, so you’d need an infinite frequency response. In reality, the lower your frequency response, the more smoothed out the step will actually be. If it’s too low, the signal doesn’t even have time to fully transition to the other level by the time you switch the pulse back, resulting in a small wobble that never reaches either level.

Answer (score 5):

You asked why to use modulation.

Modulation changes the frequencies of the signal so it "fits" better with the frequency response of the system.

For example, radio antennas are (more-or-less) band-pass filters, and you're only allowed to use a certain band anyway. When you transmit a signal by radio you have to make it fit within that band.

With Visible Light Communication you should have some more freedom to choose your own frequency, but your system still might not like certain frequencies.

Ambient light consists of very low frequencies <2Hz including 0Hz. So if your system relies on 0Hz for communication, it's likely to be confused by ambient light. If light off means 0 and light on means 1, then your system will get confused when I turn on the light in the room. So you design it to avoid very low frequencies. If you make it so a 100Hz flash means 0 and a 200Hz flash means 1 (that's FSK), it's not going to be confused by ambient light.

You might discover additional constraints when you construct your system and measure its frequency response. Most likely, the LED and/or the photodetector won't be able to respond to high frequencies. When you measure it, you'll find a "window" of frequencies that can get from the signal source, through the transmit amplifier (if you have one), LED, optical path, detector, and receive amplifier (if you have one), and to the signal receiver.

This "window" is your band, and the width of the band is the bandwidth (who woulda thunk?). It won't be a sharp transition, though. It won't be like 990kHz works and 991kHz doesn't. Rather, frequencies will get transmitted worse and worse as you move closer to the edge of the band. So you have to cut it off at some point and say "past this frequency the transmission is too poor". Traditionally, we find where the frequency response is 3dB weaker than the middle, and we call that the edge - though that rule of thumb does assume the edge is nicely shaped.

Then, to send data as quickly as possible, you want to work out a modulation scheme that packs your data into the band as efficiently as possible. That's a whole separate topic and out of scope here. The [Shannon-Hartley formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) gives a theoretical maximum amount of data that you can send in a certain bandwidth with a certain signal power and noise power.

Of course, you don't have to design an optimal modulation scheme - if you're not too concerned about data rate you can use something simple, like FSK. Many systems do.

One gotcha when thinking about modulation for beginners: you need to realize that *every* signal has frequency content. It's tempting to think that AM or ASK has only one frequency, since it modulates the amplitude, not the frequency. But when you take your 1MHz carrier frequency, and modulate it with a 0.2MHz signal, and then measure the frequencies in your modulated signal, you find that it does actually use the whole band 0.8MHz-1.2MHz. If you try to send that through a communications link whose frequency response only works for the band 0.95MHz-1.05MHz, the other side will get a mangled signal.

Another gotcha: if you have, say, a 200kbps digital signal, as a wave it actually contains frequencies up to 2MHz and higher, not just 200kHz. To limit the signal to 200kHz you have to "smear out" the edges, e.g. with a low-pass filter. When you measure the frequencies in a square wave you see that it contains not just the square wave frequency, but also odd-numbered multiples of it. If you send it through a low-pass filter to remove those, the wave looks a lot more sine-y.

Comment: A good way to think about why a 1000Hz signal modulated at 200Hz would include components at 800Hz and 1200Hz is to consider that if one were to multiply a 1000Hz signal with a pair of 1001Hz signals 90 degrees apart for one second, both products would be positive half the time and negative half the time, with the positive and negative portions precisely cancelling each other out.  If one were to do the multiplication for only half a second, the product using at least one of the two phases of the 1001Hz signal would have a positive portion and negative portions that were unbalanced.

Comment: If one were to amplitude-modulate the 1000Hz signal at 1Hz before multiplying by the 1001Hz signals, the effect of that would be the same as doing the modulation *after* the multiplication, which would for at least one of the multiplied waveforms cause the positive portion to be amplified more than the negative portion, or vice versa, creating an imbalance that would be perceived as frequency content.

Answer (score 4):

> Also some people directly applies bitstream to LED while some modulating bitstream with AC and apply. What is the difference?

You don't say what sort of communication you're doing.

If it's across open space in a lit area, then there are many sources of "noise" that can confuse the receiver.  Outdoors, the flickering of sunlight through trees is pretty random.  Indoors, fluorescent or LED lamps will have a flicker frequency.

If you transmit only your raw datastream, this makes it very hard for the receiver to recognise what's data and what's noise.

If you modulate the data onto a fixed frequency carrier, the receiver can use a bandpass filter tuned to the same frequency to reject most of the unwanted background light.

Answer (score 2):

Small signal analysis is used to analyze the AC (or frequency) effects of nonlinear circuit elements. You can linearize an element such as a diode to turn it into a linear element and it makes the analysis and math easier.

Since communication with LED's involves turning them on and off very fast, it is important to understand how fast you can do that and also how to optimize the current source that will drive the LED. The bandwidth will also be determined by the diode and parasitic elements such as inductance and capacitance that arise from materials in the LED and construction.

> Also some people directly applies bitstream to LED while some
> modulating bitstream with AC and apply. What is the difference?

A bitstream is nonlinear, usually to analyze frequency we do an (AC) frequency sweep and to help determine bandwidth and also for linear analyses